# Type qualifiers (const) and complex declarations

Tags: c, pointers, constants, variable-declaration

Say we have such declaration :

```
int **const*** k;
```

Then, it could be well translated literally (according to cdecl.org) to

> declare k as pointer to pointer to pointer to const pointer to pointer
>   to int

However, still, I'm not sure to understand what it does not permit? Which operation does it restrict? Could we still do

```
(***k)++
```

In other words, what is the effect of adding const there?

And... Same question for

```
int *const**const* k;
```

Which difference would it make?

Thanks!

Comment: It's good for a question, but don't do weird things in real life, everyone will hate you.

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/2171035

Comment: There's a quote by someone: "The C syntax is a boon to teachers of trivia and people who like to make fun of the language, but not actually a problem".

Comment: I was waiting for someone to comment! Actually, I'm making a kind of C interpreter. Hence why I must be able to reproduct accurately even the most unusual types! Else, I wouldn't even bother asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> still, I'm not sure to understand what it does not permit?

It does not permit the modification that `***k` points to.

> Could we still do

```
(***k)++
```

**No**. You can't. This is because `***K` is a pointer to pointer to pointer to `const` pointer and you can't modify it. But yes, modification to `K`, `*k`, `**k` is valid.

For the sake of convenience, you can understand this as follows:

```
int *const k;     // k is a const pointer to integer. No modification to k.  
int *const *k;    // *k is a const pointer to integer. No modification to *k.  
int *const **k;   // **k is a const pointer to integer. No modification to **k.  
int *const ***k;  // ***k is a const pointer to integer. No modification to ***k.  
int **const ***k; // ***k is a const pointer to integer. No modification to ***k.
```

Comment: Aren't `const` protecting `int **`?

Comment: No. In these cases they are not.

Comment: I thought `const` protects its left side, unless there is nothing to its left, then and only then, it protects its right side.. Why this doesn't apply here?

Comment: What do you think, what is the difference between `int const *p` and `int *const p?

Comment: Now it's clear.. Two years without C++ is hard.. I'm refreshing my knowledge nowadays, +1 nice explanation my friend.

Comment: Do you remember? Once you told me to learn about pointers and I replied to you that "I am a bit afraid of this pointer thing" :)

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the point. So with "int \*const**const* k", we could do (**k)++, (****k)++, but not (*k)++ and (***k)++ right?

Comment: @haccks Now I do remember... :))

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun; Oh! That's nice. Good memory. I think its about 4 to 5 months ago.

Comment: @haccks I'm looking for that question now :D

Comment: Me too :D. Lets find that question :)

Comment: @Yannick; You got it now. Congratulations! :)

Comment: Okie. Just a quick and dirty question too. For example, char ((* const k)[5][6]). Basically, I could modify here the content of the array to which 'k' points to, but I could not increment k, is that right? In other words, const only applies to the element on his left, righty? Thanks, a lot!

Comment: @Yannick; Yes. You are going right. Now my tern, What about `const int *p` ? :)

Comment: @Yannick; Are you there? Answer my question. If not then I will explain you (do not hesitate to clear your questions).

Comment: Well, I would say you cannot modify on what p points to? in other words, 'ints' are not modifiable but p is?

Comment: @Yannick; Excellent. Now you understand it very well.

Comment: Well, chosen answer for sure :)